# How can I find and replace characters in the relatively new Snowflake online interface, SnowPipe

Tags: replace, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The old snowflake interface has a great control f feature to search for characters, and a shift control feature to replace them

This feature does not appear to be present in the new Snowsight GUI interface

Does anyone know how one could search and replace features

Comment: Do you mean the New Web UI?  Snowpipe is a technology for continuous  data loading

Answer (score 4):

The new UI is called Snowsight, not Snowpipe.  Assuming that is what you are looking for, there are limited amount of keyboard shortcuts currently available.  These can be viewed by using the following command:

press `[CMD]+[SHIFT]+[?] (Mac)` or `[CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[?] (Windows)`

I would recommend leveraging Snowflake's Community site or Support to request new functionality to the new UI as needed.  It is still a fairly new interface and there are new features being released often.  Also keep in mind that the old interface is still available.

For reference in the docs:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-worksheets.html#keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

Mike was quite right, Snowsight has is a wonderful interface, but there are a limited number of shortcuts. Find and replace is not yet present.

He was also right, shortcuts can be viewed with:

```
 [CMD]+[SHIFT]+[?] (Mac) or [CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[?] (Windows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Applicable in Snowsight

```
[CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[H]
```

enter text to be replaced, and hit enter
enter replacement text, and hit enter
confirm Yes/No/All/Stop

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTRL+SHIFT+H. It will first prompt the text and then replace

Answer (score -1):

```
[CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[R]

 (Windows)
```

it will ask what to search, then on pressing `[ENTER]` it will ask with what to replace.